# Getting fairly low internet speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I have a WiFi connection at my home with a 1 Mbps plan. Now this means that I should be generally getting around 110-125 KBps speed, but for some reason my speed is always in the 20-50 range. I have no downloads in the background, no torrents running no games nothing.

I am using windows 10, and I am aware that automatic updates cannot be disabled, therefore I've set my connection as metered to get rid of it.

Even if I try to connect using LAN I get only slight improvements. My ISP says that everything is correct on the server side, however I get crappy speeds on both my PC and my Windows Phone.

My router is a Tenda 150Mbps model - N3. Speedtest.net also shows a poor speed, most recent test [here](http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/5378684082)

What can I do to improve my internet speed?

Comment: Do you know on which layer is ISP specifying the 1 Mb/s speed? If it's layer 2, you could be getting the advertised speed from speedtest.

Comment: @AndrejaKo I have no idea about layers, my ISP never mentioned it

Comment: Well it could very easily happen that 1/2 of those 1 Mb/s go to error correction coding and other miscellaneous stuff needed to keep WiFI connection alive.

Comment: What type of 802.11 connection are you using specifically?  I ask this question even though I know it's an ISP issue

Comment: @AndrejaKo well then how do I stop that from happening?

Comment: @Ramhound Acc to my router - 11b/g mixed mode

Comment: The speeds your getting are typical for 802.11b/g connections

Comment: @YaddyVirus If it's an ISP issue, you don't. That's how standard works. Only option you might have is to try to get higher speed. The net speed you have, to me looks like expected value for 1 Mb/s plan on WiFi.